# Text on Sprites in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text, sprite

I'm trying to make an application that has sprites going down the screen with numbers in them. The Text(Script) component only works for 3D objects. I've tried using Text Mesh and making that a child of the sprites but I need them to be instantiated as a Prefab. So when I load the sprite in as a prefab it loses it's relationship to the Text Mesh. Does anyone know of a solution that worked for them?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it depending upon your requirement. I will show you two of the most basic.

1- Use 2D Sprite and TextMesh.

[image: Reference 1]

2- Use Canvas Image and Text Objects.
[image: Reference 2]

P.S First one, that is 2D Sprite can be Instantiated directly in the hierarchy but for 2nd(Canvas Image) you need to instantiate it inside the canvas obj means as a child of canvas object.